# How to tell package.json to look for in a subfolder to build an app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, package

I created "create-react-app" in a subfolder called client. My package.json has to be in the root directory though (heroku).

This is the structure:

```
  - app
    - client
      - node_modules
      - index.js
      - components
    - ...
    - package.json
    - Procfile
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "firebase": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

How to tell package.json to look for the app in the client subfolder and build it there?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your NODE_PATH environment variable like this:

```
export NODE_PATH=path/to/app/node_modules
```

You can find more information about it in the official docs:
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Comment: Thanks Alberto. Maybe silly question but where / how I can set env in Node? Should I add it to package.json / console or something else? Thanks!

Comment: There are different ways to set env variables:  
- You can simply enter that on your shell before running npm install. That env variable will be removed once you close the terminal  
- You can set it in your .bashrc file. It will save it permanently (I would not recommend doing it this way in your case)

Comment: Thanks. So I went to cd myapp, type: export NODE_PATH=client/node_modules/ then type npm start: react-scripts: command not found + Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install? I am pretty sure the path is correct. Is there anything I do wrong?